CDF and PDF of dependent variables originating from a real life shock models
Suppose there are two sources of shocks and a system with two components. Shock A can affect the first component and Shock B can affect both the components. I am trying to find the joint distribution of the lifetime of the system. Here it's clear that if the first component is affected, the lifetime of the second component will be censored but if the second is failed, like suppose the body of the system has melted,the first component will also get destroyed and not censored. This type of scenerio is called semi competing risk but with a very few example in engineering field. How to find the PDF and CDF of system lifetime?
My approach is to take two independent shocks $U_1$ and $U_2$ which follows some distribution $F(\cdot,\theta_i)$, and take two variables $T_1$ and $T_2$ and find the joint distribution $(T_1,T_2)$ where $T_1=U_1$ and $T_2=min(U_1,U_2)$. Is this approach correct? And what will be the joint PDF and CDF in this scenerio?
